# Better way to retain/pass data between activities

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am making an Android app using the [Parse SDK](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide). What I am struggling with is the flow of creating a post. Currently, in my main activity, a user selects the type of post (photo, video, etc.) takes a photo/video and goes to the next activity called `NewActivity`. In this activity, a user can review the photo/video and edit the privacy or place of the post. to change the privacy or place launches a new activity for each.

The main problem I'm having is retaining and passing this `Post` object between the activities.

My first (bad) solution was just to pass the data with the intent in a Bundle, but this soon got very messy as I really needed to pass a `Post` object between the activities. I switched from that solution to using a Singleton class called, `DataHolder`.

In each activity, I call `DataHolder.getInstance()` and when the create post button is clicked, I create a new `Post` object by executing: `DataHolder.getInstance().setPost(new Post())`. In the following activities, as the user enters more information about a post, I set the Post's properties.

This was all working well until I ran into this issue. When I would return to my app (presumably it had been killed) I would get a `NullPointerException` because the Post object was null. I was looking through the [Android docs on passing data between activites/services](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3) and needed a little help.

Should I be using the Singleton class pattern here? What would be the most efficient and easiest way to pass this `Post` object between the activities? Should I use an application singleton? I would use `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, but the `Post`object is a `ParseObject` so this is not an option. Should I avoid passing the data altogether by using Fragments for the privacy and place activities (though they have different screens and different action bars)? Should I use `startActivityForResult` for the privacy and place activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider that the app could be killed at any moment for any reason and be prepared for this. You could use something like a session object to communicate between activities. You can save it / load it as often as needed so you will not run the risk of loosing data. If you cannot serialize the actual object (eg the ParseObject) you could serialize the parts needed in order to reconstruct it (ie save the image in a temp folder and load it on demand).